# Where condition from multiple values to a multiple values

Tags: mysql

I want to count the proceeded_acct_creation applications using sub query, the condition is the date from the main query is equal to the date in sub query and the application id in sub query must be in main query. The problem is the sub query has many application id too.

**applicants table**

```
id    | name
1     | John Doe
2     | Jane Doe
```

**applicant_remarks table**

```
id    | applicant_id    | status_id    | updated_at
1     | 1               | 2            | 2019-04-10 11:40:12
2     | 2               | 2            | 2019-04-10 11:42:56
3     | 2               | 4            | 2019-04-10 11:46:21
```

**expected output**

```
GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id)    | proceeded_acct_creation
1,2                            | 1
```

**my output**

```
GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id)    | proceeded_acct_creation
1,2                            | 0
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id),
DATE(remarks.updated_at) AS `date`,
IFNULL(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM applicant_remarks
    WHERE status_id = 4
    AND DATE(updated_at) = DATE(remarks.updated_at)
    AND applicant_id IN (GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id))
    GROUP BY DATE(remarks.updated_at)
  ),
    0
) AS proceeded_acct_creation
FROM applicants
INNER JOIN applicant_remarks remarks ON remarks.applicant_id = applicants.id
WHERE remarks.status_id = 2
GROUP BY DATE(remarks.updated_at)
HAVING `date` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY remarks.updated_at DESC
```

The problem lies in this part:

```
IFNULL(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM applicant_remarks
    WHERE status_id = 4
    AND DATE(updated_at) = DATE(remarks.updated_at)
    AND applicant_id IN (GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id))
    GROUP BY DATE(remarks.updated_at)
  ),
    0
) AS proceeded_acct_creation,
```

The

```
applicant_id IN (GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id))
```

must be

```
GROUP_CONCAT(applicant_id) IN (GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id))
```

but it returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: yes its invalid. No idea what you want it to mean. Show some sample data and expected output. Don't wrap `DATE()` around types that are already dates.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I already updated the question.

Comment: In the `IFNULL` section, is the `WHERE status_id = 4` on purpose? Because your outer query define `WHERE remarks.status_id = 2`.

Comment: Yes. First, I'll get all the status = 2 then count all the status that became 4 in the same day.

Comment: Ok, understood. For the part `AND applicant_id IN (GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id))` , can you try to change it to `AND applicant_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id) FROM applicants)` and run it?

Comment: The query becomes slow.

Comment: So means that in the applicants table there are a lot of ids, correct? How long it takes to get result?

Comment: Yes, I have many applications and remarks. From 0.4s to 24s.

Comment: How many ids in there? If you do this `AND applicant_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(applicants.id) FROM applicants WHERE applicant_id in (1,2))`, will it be much faster?

Comment: I'd do this. AND applicant_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(applicant_remarks.applicant_id) FROM applicant_remarks WHERE status_id = 2) and it works. Thanks :)